# Reconstruct scene like Photosynth

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Is there any open source code which does similar to MS [Photosynth](http://photosynth.net)

> Photosynth is a potent mixture of two
>   independent breakthroughs: the ability
>   to reconstruct the scene or object
>   from a bunch of flat photographs, and
>   the technology to bring that
>   experience to virtually anyone over
>   the Internet.
>
> Using techniques from the field of
>   computer vision, Photosynth examines
>   images for similarities to each other
>   and uses that information to estimate
>   the shape of the subject and the
>   vantage point the photos were taken
>   from. With this information, we
>   recreate the space and use it as a
>   canvas to display and navigate through
>   the photos.
>
> Providing that experience requires
>   viewing a LOT of data though—much more
>   than you generally get at any one time
>   by surfing someone’s photo album on
>   the web. That’s where our Seadragon™
>   technology comes in: delivering just
>   the pixels you need, exactly when you
>   need them. It allows you to browse
>   through dozens of 5, 10, or 100(!)
>   megapixel photos effortlessly, without
>   fiddling with a bunch of thumbnails
>   and waiting around for everything to
>   load. About this Release
>
> Photosynth comes from a passionate
>   little startup of two dozen people in
>   Microsoft Live Labs. We are
>   scientists, engineers, and designers
>   working like crazy to deliver on
>   Photosynth’s promise.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not entirely sure whether this is Programming Related.  Photosynth like Photoshop etc are tools that may be used at the periphery of software development but are hardly "Programming" tools.

Comment: There is a huge amount of research papers and I believe the author published paper on describing technology behind photosynth - i was doing similar research ...

Comment: Open source doesn't pay very many PhDs' salaries.

Comment: How does this question belongs to superuser?  
It's not a dumping ground for everything!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest thing I've found to an open source Photosynth is Insight3D.  It can be found here:
http://insight3d.sourceforge.net/  While parts of Insight3D are open source and it can be downloaded for free, there are libraries included that are not open source such as the SIFT feature detector.

Bundler ( http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/ ) may also meet your needs.  Bundler is very connected to Photosynth ( http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/ ) It requires a bit more to get it running.  It doesn't have any GUI and has to be compiled.

*Update*

I have an update to report in the area of open source structure from motion applications. **OpenMVG** is a photo reconstruction project that is being actively developed (https://github.com/openMVG/openMVG). It contains reusable libraries as well as a series of executables that comprise the various step of a photo reconstruction pipeline.

*Update 2*

**Mapillary** has released a structure from motion project called OpenSfM. https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM. It has a some sweet features such as:

- Support for panoramas
- Sensor fusion with GPS and accelerometers
- An example implementation of a web viewer

Comment: this is great..let me try insight

Answer (score 4):

You could just try a few queries on Google before posting a question.

- **[OpenPhotoVR](http://openphotovr.org/)** seems quite nice.
- Checkout this **[Photosynth Rival topic](http://photosynth.net/discussion.aspx?cat=6b63cb81-8b57-4d5d-a978-41d5509bf59a&dis=1de0ba11-2eea-4cb3-907a-252fb30f1200)** on the Photosynth forums
- **[PixelStruct](http://da.vidr.cc/projects/pixelstruct/)** from David Roberts

Comment: The whole point of SO is getting answers which Google would not give you. Answers that can be answered by Google are truly useless here.

Comment: i was expecting people to share their experiences of using the various packages and alternatives here...and the differences between them

Comment: just to make it clear - the previous remark is in favor of your question (iceman) and referred to the remark made in this answer (which as stated could be looked up on Google). (as a wise Chinese man once said: "there are no stupid questions just stupid answers" )

Comment: ah but then what happens if someone finds the answer here but searched in google, they would have then got an answer from SO, but Google gave it to them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) . It is not what Photosynth does but it is a pretty powerful opensource for creating panoramic images.